# Cocos2D-X on Android not running

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-virtual-device, cocos2d-x

I've been trying to get started using Cocos2D-X, because I wanted to play around with the idea of making an app that is compatible with Android and iOS. I have been going through a tutorial (http://www.raywenderlich.com/11283/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-getting-started), and it explains how to get the program running using eclipse, but I have followed the steps it details, and not got the same results.

When I run the program in eclipse, it will launch an AVD, which will go to the slide to unlock screen. When I unlock, I am presented with a black screen.

I will include the console log eclipse has produced a the bottom, as it may have said something which might relate as to why I can not get this program to work.

Finally, I will just say, I have not altered any code in the Android project, it is exactly as the Cocos2D-X scripts created it, which is why I am confused as to why it will not work.

Thank you for reading, and I hope you are able to help me.

Console Log:

```
[2012-07-13 09:59:11 - com.test.samplecocos2dxandroid.samplecocos2dxandroid] ------------------------------
[2012-07-13 09:59:11 - com.test.samplecocos2dxandroid.samplecocos2dxandroid] Android Launch!
[2012-07-13 09:59:11 - com.test.samplecocos2dxandroid.samplecocos2dxandroid] adb is running normally.
[2012-07-13 09:59:11 - com.test.samplecocos2dxandroid.samplecocos2dxandroid] Performing com.test.samplecocos2dxandroid.samplecocos2dxandroid activity launch
[2012-07-13 09:59:11 - com.test.samplecocos2dxandroid.samplecocos2dxandroid] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'Android2.2'
[2012-07-13 09:59:11 - com.test.samplecocos2dxandroid.samplecocos2dxandroid] Uploading com.test.samplecocos2dxandroid.samplecocos2dxandroid.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-07-13 09:59:12 - com.test.samplecocos2dxandroid.samplecocos2dxandroid] Installing com.test.samplecocos2dxandroid.samplecocos2dxandroid.apk...
[2012-07-13 09:59:19 - com.test.samplecocos2dxandroid.samplecocos2dxandroid] Success!
[2012-07-13 09:59:19 - com.test.samplecocos2dxandroid.samplecocos2dxandroid] Starting activity com.test.samplecocos2dxandroid.samplecocos2dxandroid on device emulator-5554
[2012-07-13 09:59:21 - com.test.samplecocos2dxandroid.samplecocos2dxandroid] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.test.samplecocos2dxandroid/.samplecocos2dxandroid }
```

Comment: What cocos2d-x version do you have? Emulator give problems sometimes with android emulator. You could try use a real device. Emulator is too slow to develop a game using cocos2d-x.

Comment: I am using the latest version of Cocos2D-x, cocos2d-2.0-rc2-x-2.0.1. Would this be causing an issue?

Comment: Yes, just someone has answer the same thing ^^, thats the reason, valid the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of Cocos2d-x which utilizes OpenGL ES 2.0 it will not work under the emulator. The emulator does not support OpenGL ES 2.0. In addition using an emulator is not really useful while developing a game as the performance will be abysmal.

Comment: Ah, I see. So this would most likely work if I were to run it on an android device as opposed to the emulator? I hadn't thought about testing it on device. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: `The emulator does not support OpenGL ES 2.0` I'm not sure that this is true for Genymotion's emulators.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to add "GPU emulation" to the hardware properties of the virtual android device

Answer (score 0):

You can use genymotion emulators, it support OpenGL ES 2.0 and also it works like a native device.